# ActionLink can't access root folder - MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, actionlink, html.actionlink

I have an .Net MVC 3 web application that has the following structure

- root

  - Views

    - Account

      - LoginPage.aspx
  - Controllers

    - AccountController
  - Areas

    - Course

      - Index.aspx

Imagine I am currently at the **Index.aspx** page in the Course area, and I would have a button that would forward me to the **LoginPage.aspx**

In a ASP.Net MVC I would call http://localhost/Account/Login that it would lead me to the correct page. If I just write it down on the browser it works!

But I would like to use the HTML Helper **ActionLink**, so I tried:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Log on", "Login",  "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new {  id = "logonLink", data_dialog_title = "Logon" })%>
```

It get the relative path: http://localhost/Course/Account/Login

I tried also:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Log on", "Login",  "../Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new {  id = "loginLink", data_dialog_title = "Login" })%>
```

I got the error message: **Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.**

I also tried the relative path:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Log on", "Login",  "~/Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new {  id = "loginLink", data_dialog_title = "Login" })%>
```

And it lead me to:

http://localhost/Course/~/Account/Login

I would really appreciate how to find a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Log on", "Login",  "Account", new { area = "" } , new {  id = "logonLink", data_dialog_title = "Logon" })%>
```

The key is the `area = ""` bit. When using `Url.Action` or `Html.ActionLink` with areas, if you don't specify the `area` route value, MVC will only look for a match in the current area.

It get's even more important when using partial views/templates, since they can be rendered in Views in different areas.

So if using areas, get into the habit of *always* specifying the `area` route value, unless using `Url.RouteUrl` or `Html.RouteLink`.